# how to add array elements in scrollview during the button click

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to add the elements in scroll view during the button click.. if the elements add means the scroll view want to become big. depends upon the adding elements in scroll view.. the elements should be added one by one in scrollview when i clicked the button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your UIView elements with `[self.scroll addSubview:myView]` and resize your content size accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain one `height index` in viewcontroller say

```
float = scrollViewheight;
```

When adding any object say adding `UILabel` to `scrollView` then `increase scrollViewheight` like this

```
UILabel *lblText = [UILabel new];
lblText.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,280,22);

[scrollView addSubview:lblText];

//update scrollViewheight
scrollViewheight = lblText.frame.origin.y+lblText.frame.size.height;

//update scrollView's content size
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0,scrollViewheight);
```

When adding `new object` use `scrollViewheight`

```
UILabel *lblText1 = [UILabel new];
lblText1.frame = CGRectMake(20,scrollViewheight+20,280,22);

[scrollView addSubview:lblText1];

//update scrollViewheight
scrollViewheight = lblText1.frame.origin.y+lblText1.frame.size.height;

//update scrollView's content size
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0,scrollViewheight);
```

**EDIT** : Just formatted

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    // adds new view to scrollView
    [self.scrollView addSubview:anotherView];
    int padding = 10;
    // set scrollView content size
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentView.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + padding + anotherView.frame.size.height)]; 
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, anotherView.frame.origin.y) animated:YES]; // scrolls to new view
}
```

Hope it helps